# File uploading with ColdFusion, too big of file timing out?

Tags: coldfusion, upload, timeout

A client has the admin ability to upload a PDF to their respective directory and have it listed on their website. All of this works dandy until a PDF reaches a certain file size that makes the server time out. This causes an error and the file uploaded will not succeed.

As mentioned in the title, we are using ColdFusion with a  command. Is there any java/jquery/flash modules or applications that could resolve this issue?

Edit: For clarification, this is the web server timing out and not ColdFusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change setting in CFadministrator > settings > Request Size Limits

Answer (score 2):

On the action page, you can use CFSETTING to extend the timeout, allowing the page to run longer than it otherwise is allowed:

```
<cfsetting requesttimeout="{seconds}">
```

Obviously, replace {seconds} with the number of seconds you want to allow.

For clarification, this is only if it is CF timing out, and not the web server or client (browser).

Also, most web servers also have a file size limit set for uploads.  Make sure this is set to a reasonable size.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Ben! We do indeed have the requesttimeout set and it is at a very large amount for this particular client. The error is coming from the web server and we do not want to change that just for one client.

Comment: If you can't change the web server, ask your client to use FTP or email the PDF? ColdFusion has <cfftp> and <cfpop> you can use...

Comment: @knawlejj -- If the web server is stopping the request, then it doesn't get to ColdFusion (or java, or whatever) so, other than upping the global timeout on the web server itself or using a different delivery method (as Henry suggested) I think you're out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider using the cffileupload tag.  It's a flash based uploader that might give you a better result.

Alternatively, you might be able to find some way using a flash upload tool to break up the upload into chunks and put it back together again somehow to meet the hard limits of your web server.

If you figure it out please be sure to share it here, this is an interesting problem!

Answer (score 0):

Your will need to pay attention to the iiS configuration > RequestLimits > maxallowedcontentLength
setting, as well as the request timeout setting in ColdFusion administrator.

If a large file is uploaded that exceeds 30 MBytes, then iiS will throw a 404 error by default.
Suggest you increase the setting (I changed mine to 300 MBytes) to the maximum you might expect then change the timeout setting in ColdFusion to suit the size of file and the bandwidth that is available on your web hosting site in concert with bandwidth available to your clients (worst case).

You ought to test the upload with an approprate size file to make sure it all works but make sure that the site you test from has equivalent bandwidth to your clients.  E.g. test from a site that uses ADSL.